# v3 library in app purchase: How to make download possible | Android

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

My problem is that I don't know how to make a download of the upgrade version possible and I don't know where I must put the code of the upgrade version.

This is my code from https://github.com/anjlab/android-inapp-billing-v3:

```
BillingProcessor bp;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.upgrade);
    setTitle("Upgrade");
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

    bp = new BillingProcessor(this, "/*Here's my license key from GooglePlay*/", this);

    Button buy = (Button) findViewById((R.id.buy));
    buy.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick (View view) {
            bp.purchase(upgrade.this, "upgrade");
        }
    });
}

// IBillingHandler implementation

@Override
public void onBillingInitialized() {
/*
* Called when BillingProcessor was initialized and it's ready to purchase
*/
}

@Override
public void onProductPurchased(String productId, TransactionDetails details) {
/*
* Called when requested PRODUCT ID was successfully purchased
*/
}

@Override
public void onBillingError(int errorCode, Throwable error) {
/*
* Called when some error occurred. See Constants class for more details
*
* Note - this includes handling the case where the user canceled the buy dialog:
* errorCode = Constants.BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_USER_CANCELED
*/
}

@Override
public void onPurchaseHistoryRestored() {
/*
* Called when purchase history was restored and the list of all owned PRODUCT ID's
* was loaded from Google Play
*/
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (!bp.handleActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    if (bp != null) {
        bp.release();
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

My question is now how to make a download of this upgrade possible? Where must be the code of the upgrade version?

Thanks for answering!